# Problems with texturing a certain model

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, import, baking

So I exported a Valkyrie Model from R6 onto Blender and I managed to texture it all except for the arms, as show in the picture the arms are black when they should be obviously skin color with tatoo's as you can see from the texture file. Is there a solution to this problem so that it textures correctly.[image]

[image: Texture File]

[image: UV Layer]

[image: Geometry]

Comment: Hello, please add a screenshot of the UVs overlayed over the image texture

Comment: i've added the uv overlay i think

Comment: When in edit mode (Press tab while the body is selected), select the arms polygons. the geometry should overlay over the image you provided. If it isn't located on the pixels of the tattoo, try to reposition it

Comment: the pixels is on where the tatoo would be, attached a picture

Comment: You can see these parts are missing from your image. The squared pattern means there is no color information there, explaining the black color. Try to replace this image by the first one you provided

Comment: Sorry I'm unsure about how to replace it with the first image I provided

Comment: Go into the uv editor and browse your computer for the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ln2I.png

Comment: got it to work, the tga file is weird idk why, i took a screenshot of the texture and attached it to the color node and it was fixed (sorry for bad english)